# Echo input into output, at the right place

Tags: c, input, io, user-input, io-redirection

I want to insert the input given to a program into its output, in the moment it is read.

For instance, given the program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double x, y;
  printf("Soma de dois números:\n");
  printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
  scanf("%lf", &y);
  double soma = x + y;
  printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", x, y, soma);
  return 0;
}
```

when it is run with input redirection, I want the input inserted into the output, like the following:

```
$ echo -e "10\n25\n" | ./a.out
sum of two numbers
first number: 12
second number: 25
12.000000 + 25.000000 = 37.000000
```

Is there any library or tool to help me with that?

*Edited* **Context**: I intend to use this for correcting program exercises in a programming course. I want to see/show the program input and output as if it were run in an interactive console with the input being typed interactively, although the input is redirect from a text file.

Comment: You want the input the program is receiving from the standard input stream to be echoed to the standard output stream? The easiest way to do that is simply to insert print calls in the program. Given that you are using `scanf`, you can reconstruct the input by printing the scanned value, although this produces differences such as showing “12” whether the user entered “12”, “       12”,  or “012”. To exactly echo the input, you would need to stop using `scanf`. You could get each character one by one and echo it, and then you would parse the characters…

Comment: … Or, if it suits your purposes, you could read a line at a time with `fgets`, echo it, and then parse the line with `sscanf`. Another alternative would be to replace the standard library input routines with your own versions that echo input, but that is on another level of program construction and is likely more than you want to do. You should update the question with contextual information about what goals you are trying to achieve with this and whether the line-by-line or other suggestions above suffice.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do that.  The problem is that when you type at the terminal, the terminal driver echoes the characters typed.  When you have I/O redirection (from a pipe or a file), the terminal driver is not involved, and neither the disk driver nor the pipe code echoes to standard output.  One option might be to use a pseudo-terminal for the input to your program — but I've not tried it so that might not work.  Or you could test to see whether the input is a terminal, doing nothing special if it is a terminal, and echoing the result of the input if it is.  POSIX `isatty()` helps.

Comment: On Unix you can use the `isatty()` function to check if standard input is coming from a terminal. If it's a terminal, display the prompt and read the input (the terminal driver will echo the input). If not, read the input and then display the prompt with the input appended.

Comment: I have edited the question for better contextualization.

Comment: Given your edit, you should probably look at 
W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321637739)
2013 — and Chapter 19 (Pseudo-Terminals).  The `pty` program in section 19.5 is likely to be what you want, or very close to what you want.  And I said "fairly fiddly" — I was not exaggerating; if anything, it's a serious case of meiosis.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment:

> There isn't an easy way to do that. The problem is that when you type at the terminal, the terminal driver echoes the characters typed. When you have I/O redirection (from a pipe or a file), the terminal driver is not involved, and neither the disk driver nor the pipe driver echoes to standard output.

One option might be to use a pseudo-terminal for the input to your program — but I've not tried it so that might not work.  It's also fairly fiddly to set up (though there might well be a utility available on Linux, in particular, to do the job).

Or you could test to see whether the input is a terminal, doing nothing special if it is a terminal, and echoing the result of the input if it is. POSIX function [`isatty()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) determines whether the given file descriptor is a terminal or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    double d;
    if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a number!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        printf("%lf\n", d);
    printf("You entered: %lf\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

With that saved as source file `tty47.c`, I can run:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common tty47.c -o tty47
$ tty47
Enter a number: 2.718282
You entered: 2.718282
$ echo "3.141593" | tty47
Enter a number: 3.141593
You entered: 3.141593
$ tty47 <<<'1.618034'
Enter a number: 1.618034
You entered: 1.618034
$
```

The first run accepts the input I type at the terminal, and that is echoed by the terminal driver.  The other two runs know that the input comes from a pipe and a file respectively, and they echo the input.  Note that the echo is not guaranteed to be exactly what the user entered — I cheated by typing numbers with 6 decimal places.  Use fewer places and you get trailing zeros; use more and the result is rounded.  You'll have to decide whether that matters.

An alternative strategy would read the input using `getchar()` or equivalent and echo each character with `putchar()` or equivalent if the input is not a terminal, and then use `sscanf()` to parse the data.  That's definitely fiddlier.